# How to float or column position boostrap datetimepicker without throwing of the datetimepicker widget

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying get bootstrap datetimepicker form to organzie to the left or float to the left if that is possible. It is fine as it is without being placed in another environment, but I want it to be side by side with a next form. I have tried everthing I could possibly think of so far, I have used the bootstrap `row` format to place it in a column (although it already uses bootstrap row and column). I also used `floats` and also `display: inline-block`.

I am trying to get the datetimepicker form `datetimepicker45`, and the `textarea` form in one column to the left, and the other form with class `form-horizontal form-event-upload eforms-right` in the second column to the right.

I Have tried everything only to see the dropdown-widget displaying incorrectly out of place. Just in case anyone ask, I am not using the bootstrap class `container`, because it is not ideal for the site I am building.
an example is here: https://jsfiddle.net/Jam1/5tsamjx5/31/

```
    <div id="eform-b" class="eform">                                                  
        <div class="eform-left">
            <div class="row">
                <div class='col-sm-12'> 
                    <label for="datetimepicker45">Date/Time</label>
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" id='datetimepicker45'/>
                </div>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    $(function () {
                        $('#datetimepicker45').datetimepicker();
                    });
                </script>
            </div>
            <div class="textarea-size">
                <textarea class="form-control" id="eInfo" rows="3" placeholder="Additional event info (optional)"></textarea>
            </div>                                                                          
        </div>
        <div class="eform-right">                                   
            <form class="form-horizontal form-event-upload eforms-right">
                <div class="form-group">                         
                    <label for="eCat">Category</label>                                
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="eCat" placeholder="eg Education">        
                </div>                                                                 
                <div class="form-group">                                   
                    <label for="eScat">SubCategory</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="eScat" placeholder="eg Mathematics">                                
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">                                  
                    <label for="eTop">Topic</label>                                
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="eTop" placeholder="eg Algebra (optional)">                        
                </div>                      
            </form>                                         
        </div>                                                              
    </div>
```

Comment: Do you have a jsfiddle, it would be easy that way

Comment: I have added the jsfiddle, please take a look at it